# MediaPlayer.GameHasControl is not working properly

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

My app failed certification because of the 6.5.1 guideline: "The application can reach a state where it pauses the users music without prompt."

I googled the solution for this problem and found out that you have to use MediaPlayer.GameHasControl to check if the user has music playing before starting the app.

When I implemented it, it didn't work. It did prompt about the pausing the music BUT it also paused it before the I had any chance to react. I tried to put the MediaPlayer.GameHasControl in the OnNavigatedTo(), Loaded() and in the constructor and it does work for awhile but the app crashes after a few second so those are not an option. Then I tried to put the in the MediaOpened event handled of my three MediaElements but no luck. Now I'm just stuck. If anyone could shed some light on this, I'll very grateful.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace RhythmCoach
{
  public partial class BeginnerExercisePage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    public BeginnerExercisePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument beginnerExerciseData = XDocument.Load("XML/BeginnerXML.xml");

        string name = string.Empty;

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))
        {

            var exercise = (from Exercised in beginnerExerciseData.Descendants("Exercised")
                            where Exercised.Attribute("name").Value == name
                            select new Exercise
                            {
                                ExImage = (string)Exercised.Element("image").Value,
                                ExGuitarAudio = (string)Exercised.Element("GuitarAudio").Value,
                                ExPianoAudio = (string)Exercised.Element("PianoAudio").Value,
                                ExSnareAudio = (string)Exercised.Element("SnareAudio").Value,
                                ExTitle = (string)Exercised.Element("title").Value
                            }).Single();

            im.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(exercise.ExImage, UriKind.Relative));
            pageTitle.Text = exercise.ExTitle;

            guitarAudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(exercise.ExGuitarAudio,UriKind.Relative);
            pianoAudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(exercise.ExPianoAudio, UriKind.Relative);
            snareAudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(exercise.ExSnareAudio, UriKind.Relative);
        }

        rbBegSnare.IsChecked = true;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbBegGuitar.IsChecked == true)
        {
            guitarAudioPlayer.Play();

        }
        else if (rbBegPiano.IsChecked == true)
        {
            pianoAudioPlayer.Play();

        }
        else
            snareAudioPlayer.Play();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbBegGuitar.IsChecked == true)
        {
            guitarAudioPlayer.Stop();
            pianoAudioPlayer.Stop();
            snareAudioPlayer.Stop();
        }
        else if (rbBegPiano.IsChecked == true)
        {
            pianoAudioPlayer.Stop();
            guitarAudioPlayer.Stop();
            snareAudioPlayer.Stop();
        }
        else
            snareAudioPlayer.Stop();
            guitarAudioPlayer.Stop();
            pianoAudioPlayer.Stop();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbBegGuitar.IsChecked == true)
        {
            guitarAudioPlayer.Pause();
            pianoAudioPlayer.Pause();
            snareAudioPlayer.Pause();
        }
        else if (rbBegPiano.IsChecked == true)
        {
            pianoAudioPlayer.Pause();
            guitarAudioPlayer.Pause();
            snareAudioPlayer.Pause();
        }
        else
            snareAudioPlayer.Pause();
            guitarAudioPlayer.Pause();
            pianoAudioPlayer.Pause();
    }

    private void rbBegGuitar_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pianoAudioPlayer.Stop();
        snareAudioPlayer.Stop();
    }

    private void rbBegPiano_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        guitarAudioPlayer.Stop();
        snareAudioPlayer.Stop();
    }

    private void rbBegSnare_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        guitarAudioPlayer.Stop();
        pianoAudioPlayer.Stop();
    }

    private void guitarAudioPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
        {
            MessageBoxResult Choice;
            Choice = MessageBox.Show("Media is currently playing, do you want to stop it?", "Stop Player", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (Choice != MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                else
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Menu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void pianoAudioPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
        {
            MessageBoxResult Choice;
            Choice = MessageBox.Show("Media is currently playing, do you want to stop it?", "Stop Player", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (Choice != MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                else
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Menu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void snareAudioPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
        {
            MessageBoxResult Choice;
            Choice = MessageBox.Show("Media is currently playing, do you want to stop it?", "Stop Player", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (Choice != MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                else
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Menu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

AND XAML

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="242*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="243*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="243*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="163*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="245*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Margin="12,17,0,28" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="BEGINNER EXERCISES" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="Black" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding ExTitle}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" Foreground="Black" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

        <Image x:Name="im" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,155" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

    <Button Grid.Row="2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,13,0,0" x:Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black" ClickMode="Release">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RhythmCoach;component/Images/appbar.transport.play.rest.png" Stretch="None" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <MediaElement Grid.Row="2" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="guitarAudioPlayer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Source="{Binding ExGuitarAudio}"  AutoPlay="False" Volume="100" MediaOpened="guitarAudioPlayer_MediaOpened" />
    <MediaElement Grid.Row="2" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="pianoAudioPlayer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Source="{Binding ExPianoAudio}"  AutoPlay="False" Volume="100" MediaOpened="pianoAudioPlayer_MediaOpened" />
    <MediaElement Grid.Row="2" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="snareAudioPlayer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Source="{Binding ExSnareAudio}"  AutoPlay="False" Volume="100" MediaOpened="snareAudioPlayer_MediaOpened" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,13,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button2_Click" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RhythmCoach;component/Images/appbar.transport.stop.rest1.png" Stretch="None" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,13,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button3_Click" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RhythmCoach;component/Images/appbar.transport.pause.rest.png" Stretch="None" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <RadioButton Content="Guitar" Grid.Row="2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,101,0,0" Name="rbBegGuitar" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Background="#BFADADAD" BorderBrush="#BFFFFFFF" Checked="rbBegGuitar_Checked" />
    <RadioButton Content="Piano" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,101,0,0" Name="rbBegPiano" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#BFA3A3A3" Foreground="Black" Checked="rbBegPiano_Checked" />
    <RadioButton Content="Snare Drum" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,101,0,0" Name="rbBegSnare" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#BF939393" Foreground="Black" Checked="rbBegSnare_Checked" />
    <my:AdControl AdUnitId="10029089" ApplicationId="05ab3750-df60-4e42-9939-ab68de9f424b" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,17,0,0" Name="adControlSmall" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RhythmCoach;component/Images/bg1.png" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will update this answer with the code I use to do the prompts after I get home. I think mine is in Loaded(). I see your mediaElements are not set to AutoPlay so that should not be the issue. If you remove the prompting altogether does the background music still pause without you pressing any buttons on the page?

Another way I've seen people handle this is instead of prompting every run of the application, you ask them on startup if they want to always pause background music when running the app. Store that setting and then you just check that on subsequent runs. It looks like you have a main menu, so one possibility would be to not let them go to your pages with music if they haven't agreed to pause the background music.

I was going to paste my code but it may have been a bit confusing so I have extracted out the meat that you're after:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    //remember don't show MessageBoxes in OnNavigatedTo..
    // better to move stuff over to Loaded as much as you can anyway
    this.Loaded += RunOnPageLoaded; //you could hook up to this event via the Designer too
}

void RunOnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool doLoad = true;
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
    {
        doLoad = PromptUserAboutBackgroundMusic();
        if (doLoad) MediaPlayer.Pause();
    }

    if (doLoad)
    {
        LoadMediaFiles();
    }
}

private bool PromptUserAboutBackgroundMusic()
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to stop your background music to play this recording?",
                                 "Stop music?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK) return true;
    return false;
}

private void LoadMediaFiles()
{
    //load your media files into your mediaelements here
    //mediaElement.AutoPlay = true;
    //mediaElement.Source = ...
}
```

While this may be what you've asked for, after looking at what you're doing I'm not so sure that MediaElements are the best thing for you to be using. If you used SoundEffectInstance's instead then the background music doesn't get paused and you don't even have to bother with any of that prompting about background music unless you want to add that feature.

Comment: Thanks for answering! yes it does pause without the prompt. Thanks for posting the code later! Hopefully it will help me solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! The code above solved it! Now it works and doesn't crash.

Comment: Now that I tested it for awhile, there's that crashing again on the prompt. If I leave the the prompt open for like 4-5 seconds it exits the app. Should it be there?  Other than that it works just great.

Comment: It should only crash if you leave a prompt up that was from OnNavigatedTo or the constructor. I think it should be OK in the Loaded event, but you could try doing the prompt from a dispatcher.BeginInvoke call and that should clear it up.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again PurpleFlux. I just can't seem to make it work. I tried to use the prompt on Loaded and almost everything else I know but still it crashes after 4 seconds or so. How do I implement Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to try to fix this bug?

Comment: nevermind, I found the solution online :) The Dispatcher.BeginInvoke did the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bool canPlayMusic = true;

        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

        if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Is it ok to stop currently playing music?",
                "Can stop music?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                canPlayMusic = false;
            }
        }

        if (canPlayMusic)
        {
            MediaPlayer.Pause();

            runBackgroundMusic();
        }
    }
```

Comment: by using the above code will pause the music player. But I want to close the music player. Because Once it is paused then if user try to increase the volume it shows the pause state of the music. So, the user can play the song again. 
So, i want to close the music player when user presses ok.
How could i do that>?????

Answer (score 0):

Before calling to MediaPlayer.GameHasControl, you can call FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); that will help to prevent the Exception from crashing your app.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I tried it in the OnNavigatedTo() but it still crashed. By crashing I mean it exited the app after 5 seconds or so.

Comment: Just giving it another look I see in OnNavigatedTo() you set rbBegSnare.IsChecked = true; which then calls .Stop() on some of the mediaElements. Try commenting that line out and see if it still pauses your music. If it fixes it there are some things you could do with flags for example.

Comment: Heh I commented on the wrong comment above. Anyway a comment for this thread: the crash in OnNavigatedTo may have been due to when you had a Messagebox prompt in there.. if you do that and don't click a button in X seconds your app will get killed because it thinks the navigation failed.